# API Calling - Error: SyntaxError: Unterminated string literal (line 8, file "Code" - Google Apps Script

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I am getting error "SyntaxError: Unterminated string literal (line 8, file "Code" while using google apps script, its working fine with another API but I don't know whats wrong with this.

```
new code is :
`function Covid19_all() {

  // Call the COVID19 API
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/all");

  // Parse the JSON reply
  var json=response.getContentText();
  var data=JSON.parse(json);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
  { 
    sheet.getRange(i+2,1).setValue([data[i]['Country']]);
    sheet.getRange(i+2,2).setValue([data[i]['CountryCode']]);
    sheet.getRange(i+2,3).setValue([data[i]['Province']]);
    sheet.getRange(i+2,4).setValue([data[i]['City']]);
    sheet.getRange(i+2,5).setValue([data[i]['Lat']]);
    sheet.getRange(i+2,6).setValue([data[i]['Lon']]);
    sheet.getRange(i+2,7).setValue([data[i]['Confirmed']]);
    sheet.getRange(i+2,8).setValue([data[i]['Deaths']]);
    sheet.getRange(i+2,9).setValue([data[i]['Recovered']]);
    sheet.getRange(i+2,10).setValue([data[i]['Active']]);
    sheet.getRange(i+2,11).setValue([data[i]['Date']]);
  }
```

and error is:
'SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input (line 8, file "Code")'

Comment: Could you show official documentation for this loop syntax in mdn: `for each(){}`?

Comment: [The for each...in statement is deprecated as the part of ECMA-357 (E4X) standard. E4X support has been removed. Consider using for...of instead.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in)

Comment: yes, I know that but haven't enabled new version yet on my browser so there is no problem in "for each" right now. the problem is with Line 8 `var data=JSON.parse(json);` if anybody can help plesae.

Comment: Disregarding the `for each` situation, there is a problem with the API response. It seems to be corrupted somehow.

Comment: Now I have changed the `for each(){}`

Answer (score 1):

I played around with it a lot, and switched it to v8 runtime and added in some awaits/async to your setup, but still am getting that error.

I then added in `console.log(json.substring(json.length - 1000));` and it is clearly not receiving the full response.

I believe that it's probably hitting a max data quota for GET request, more information can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Sorry that I couldn't share a solution.

Here's my code if you're curious: 
- I played around with making sure there were no empty strings, and that the zeroes were indeed strings, but that wasn't the issue obviously.

```
async function Covid19_all() {
  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    followRedirects: true
  };

  const response = await UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/all", requestOptions)
  const text = await response.getContentText();
  const text2 = await text.toString();
  const text3 = text2.replace(/: 0/g, ': "0"').replace(/""/g, '"dummy"');
  console.log(text3.substring(text3.length - 1000));
  const json = await JSON.parse(text3);
  console.log(json);
}
```

Hope this was helpful.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks Jack, issue is till there but it's helpful what you have shared.